# How to take input using a radio button in php

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem. Actually I'm making a quiz in php. So my client will be having 4 options which are displayed in radio buttons. So I want to get the option he/she has selected in the variable $ answer so how to do that. My code is as follows:

```
<?php

$qid = $_POST['q_id'];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
$db  = mysql_select_db('quiz', $con) or die(mysql_error());
$q   = "select * from question where qno=$qid";
$rq  = mysql_query($q,$con);

echo $rq;

if(!$rq)
{
    echo " the sql query faiiled to work ";
}else
{
    while ($sub_row=mysql_fetch_array($rq))
    {
        $id=$sub_row["qno"];
        $question=$sub_row["question"];
        $option1=$sub_row["option1"];
        $option2=$sub_row["option2"];
        $option3=$sub_row["option3"];
        $option4=$sub_row["option4"];

        echo "<h5>Q".$id." : ".$question."</br></h5>";   
        echo "</br></br>";
        echo "<h4><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option1}\">$option1</h4></br>";
        echo "<h4><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option2}\">$option2</h4></br>";
        echo "<h4><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option3}\">$option3</h4></br>";
        echo "<h4><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option4}\">$option4</h4></br></br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<input type='hidden' name='question' value='{$id}'>`

And then it's easy - `$answer = $_POST[$_POST['question']]`

Comment: `$_POST[$_POST['question']]` ?

Comment: yes. he gave a variable name to the `input type=radio` field. I suggest him to send the variable with `hidden input` and show it that way.

Comment: i can't get it. what does <input type='hidden' name='question' value='{$id}'> is doing is it geeting the user coice by radio button

Comment: No it isn't. it's getting the ID of the question - the name of the `<input type='radio'>`.

Comment: You also need to make a radio group so only one will be selected at a time. As it is now you can select all radio buttons and all values will be passed on.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. all radios have the same name - so why would you need to group them?